# EJB remote application-client

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, ejb, application-client

I am starting a new enterprise project and use `Glassfish 3` as an application server and `NetBeans 6.9` as an `IDE`. I have some `EJBs` which I want to access remotely from a desktop `Swing` application. AFAIK there are two options - either use plain `JNDI` lookup or run the `Swing` application in an application-client container and use `@EJB` annotations. I tried successfully the first option but I had to copy all `glassfish` libraries to satisfy the dependencies(about 50MB, which I don't find normal). Now I try the second option. In `NetBeans`, I create a new `Enterprise Application Client` project, add the EJB project as a dependency and press run. I get the following exception: `Sniffers with type [ejb] and type [appclient] should not claim the archive at the same time`. Now if I remove the `package` checkbox, next to the EJB project in the Project properties of application client, I get a different `ClassNotFound` exception of my remote interface.

I feel kind of stuck:( Could some more experienced guys, tell me how do they access their EJBs remotely, using `Glassfish 3`? As I have written above, I succeed with the first option, but 50MB are too much in my opinion for a simple client.

Edit: What approach would you choose for deployment and remote access from the client, if you have the business logic in `ejbs` on a remote server?

Thanks for any suggestions you have!

Wish you all the best, Petar

Comment: Did you download the full version or just web profile? The 'sniffer' is part of glassfish container that figures out which container to start when you deploy a jar file. It introspects the jar file to look for tell tale files like web.xml, etc. Since sniffer is complaining about not being able to find the ejb container, my guess is that you may have download the web profile. Try getting 'full platform'

Comment: I downloaded the full version and I think the client container is complaining because it finds two things - ejb and application client and it doesn't know which to run. But how can I reference my ejb project then?!!!

Comment: I'm not sure where you problem is but if you give me your email I'll send you a sample for you to look at

Comment: @Chuk Many thanks! Here it is - petar.minchev(at)gmail.com Just make sure your example guarantees that there is no Glassfish server installed on the client side. I will be glad if you send me an example including app-client container and also without it(completely standalone).

Comment: @Chuk - I feel like a dumbass now:( The problem was I clicked run on the application client and then Netbeans gave the sniffer exception. But if I click run on the ear, then everything is fine:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach in your case is to create a Servlet (or some other light simple component) in your server and make this guy talk to your EJB. If you choose this case, you will isolate your client/server comunication and your business logic implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have chosen EJB, so the remote communication is easier through a well defined @Remote interface. Also I won't have a web GUI, why create a servlet then and use HTTP communication? Isn't it too low level and artifical?

Comment: Yes, it is. But if you want to avoid all the application server dependencies, i think this may be an approach. Of course, the best way is have a true EJB communication with all dependencies in your client application. In some cases it may be a problem (I have an client WebStart application with 87MB, but our customer use it in a private network, so its not a problem here).